# Codelite debugger error: Failed to locate gdb! at 'gdb'?

Tags: debugging, compiler-construction, gdb, codelite

I'm trying using Codelite to try and compile some c++ projects that I wrote using DevCpp.
I don't have a lot of knowledge about compilers and debuggers.. and every time I try to compile and debug any code in Codelite, I keep getting this error saying:

Failed to locate gdb! at 'gdb'

I tried messing around with the debugger settings but nothing would work. In the build window it says:

"mingw32-make.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

again, I don't really know what that means. Could someone care to share a fix to this issue and if possible, give me a quick explanation on the difference between these compilers and debuggers?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably you are on windows. Which installer you used?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what was wrong.. I did not install the complete package. I only installed the IDE codelite but not the debugger files

http://sourceforge.net/projects/codelite/files/Releases/codelite-3.5/

in this link, dl the package: codelite-3.5.5377-mingw4.6.1-wx2.9.2.exe

for the whole debugger/compiler/ide/etc and your codes should compile.. at least mine did :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow these steps :

Open Codelite and go to :

Settings -> Build Settings -> Compilers -> Tools -> Gbd

The ' Gdb ' bar should be empty in this case , and you have to look for the ' gdb32.exe ' file .

like in the image in this site : 
[Build Setting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAH5Z.jpg)

you have to find that file in the following address :

C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin

file : gdb32.exe