# Codelite debugger error: Failed to locate gdb! at '/usr/bin/gdb'

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb, codelite

So I have just installed codelite on Ubuntu trusty (14.04) x64

Everything seems to be working fine but when I try to run the debugger I get the error in the question title and it just stops there and does nothing. I have searched far and wide and can't find a solution to this issue.

I did see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790231/codelite-debugger-error-failed-to-locate-gdb-at-gdb/10802041#10802041), but it is related to windows not Linux.

I have tried the following:

```
apt-get install gdb

apt-get install codelite-dbg

ls /usr/bin/ | grep gdb
gdb
gdbtui
gdbus
gdbus-codegen

chmod ug+s /usr/bin/gdb
ls -l /usr/bin/ | grep gdb
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root   root       5720256 Oct 30 14:47 gdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root           126 Oct 30 14:47 gdbtui
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root         35688 Apr  3  2014 gdbus
```

still getting the error and not sure what to do. The file is clearly there and executable by everybody.

Comment: making gdb be setuid-binary is a *really bad idea*. You've completely compromised your system. As far as your original problem, run codelight under `strace -f` and see what it does (and update your question with a relevant `strace` snippet).

Comment: I have reverted the file to -rwxr-xr-x, I was just demonstrating that it was something I tried, I had no intentions of leaving it like that. Thanks though, its still good advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using CodeLite 7.0 there was a bug introduced with the auto tools detection (which was fixed in git master).

The problem is that the gdb path contained an extra space `/usr/bin/gdb` at the end

To fix this, remove the extra space and the problem will go away, from:
`Settings->Build Settings->Compilers->You Compiler Name->Tools tab->Gdb`

Eran

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I cant believe I couldn't find information on that anywhere. Hopefully if somebody else has that issue they will find this. Would upvote but not enough rep, so thanks.

Comment: @Mel0n Note that you should have clearly seen that extra space in strace output.

Comment: @CandyChiu sorry for the question, but do you have gdb installed? Another solution will be to manually select gdb from `Settings->Build Settings->Compilers->You Compiler Name->Tools tab->Gdb`

Comment: @Eran I have MinGW in the path, which contains gdb.exe.  Is that good enough?

Comment: @CandyChiu If it was, we would not have this conversation on stackoverflow ;) Can you try with the weekly build for Windows? It can be found on the same download page: http://downloads.codelite.org/ it should contain a fix for gdb

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't such a problem on Linux, but had it on Windows with Codelite 8.2.1.
after having tried several paths in Settings/gdb Settings/General and in Settings->Build Settings->Compilers->You Compiler Name->Tools tab->Gdb, I just removed double quotes from this latest path, and it worked.

Comment: Totally nailed it for me on version 9.0.4 in Win10.  thanks for saving me a ton of time and frustration.  Anybody submit a bug report to the Codelite folks?

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem on Windows 10 with Codelite. For me GDB path was empty in **Settings->Build Settings->Compilers->You Compiler Name->Tools tab->Gdb**, 
Though I had MinGW installed in my system so i added my own path in "" and it worked.

**My Path : "C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/gdb32.exe"**

But as i have seen some solution where the gdb path contained an extra space /usr/bin/gdb at the end.

[Download MinGW for windows from here!](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/)